# jQuery .load() Queries/Performance

Tags: jquery

With using the jQuery .load() function, I find that at initial load, my web page performing the .load() routine tends to jolt/flicker for a sec when loading.

Once loaded though, the page is displayed instantaneously.

Can anyone suggest a means of perhaps loading these pages into cache or some other means to prevent this jolt/flicker when loading?

Thanks.

Comment: What does jolt/flicker? The page? The page contents? The part you are doing `load()` on?

Comment: Are you using the asynchronous xhr? If it's synched, your page will "freeze" until the data is loaded.

Comment: Hi, I am simply using jquery .load() function and it's the actual page contents, i.e. the DIV I am applying the .load() to.

Answer (score 2):

I had this same issue. Here's a trick. Make sure you load your data into a div that you have hidden with `.hide()`. Then to make the data you just appended or loaded into there visible, just do `.show`. This way, it will fade in instead of jolting in. You can also use the jQuery `slideDown()` or `slideUp()` which is essentially the same as `show()`.